# Printing multiple statements in cond in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

In Racket, I am trying to print multiple expressions in "cond" statement as below,

```
(let ((var `(make))
      (exp '(1 2)))
   (cond
      [(number? 2) `(hi ,var)
                   `(bye ,exp)]))
```

But only the "bye" statement is returned/printed on the screen.The first "hi" is not evalauted at all. How do I return/print both ?

Answer (score 7):

You say "returned/printed" but those are two very different things:

- If you want to things returned, then you should use [multiple values](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/values.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._values%29%29), like `(values 1 2)` (or you can return a list with the two values as a cheap hack in case you don't know about multiple values).
- If you want to print stuff, then use [`print`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._print%29%29) twice (or [`display`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._display%29%29), or [`write`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._write%29%29), or [`printf`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._printf%29%29) etc etc).

If you're a complete newbie, then it's likely that neither of these is the right solution for you.

Comment: +1 I originally wanted to talk about MV in my answer too, but given the OP's level, I figured it'd be too much to explain how to correctly use MV. :-P

Comment: In particular, I agree with returning a list, since I'm guessing this a function whose purpose is to return a list-of-statements (and the result is probably being spliced/appended into a bigger result).  So ``(list `(hi ,var) `(bye ,exp))``, or just a backtick-followed-by-``((hi ,var) (bye ,exp))``.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're not really "printing" anything, just returning the last expression (`` `(bye ,exp) `` in this case). If you want to print them, use `display`:

```
(cond ((number? 2)
       (display `(hi ,var))
       (display `(bye ,exp))))
```

Comment: Ok, to be clear I am parsing racket code to generate code (which is again in racket). Using the above solution, my result will be interpreted as (procedure args) which is not what I want. What I need is to print the two stmts one after another.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether the OP wants to *return* the data, or *print* them.

Expanding on Eli Barzilay's suggestion to *return* a list, the simplest modification would be simply to evaluate `list` on the two expressions:

```
(let ((var `(make))
      (exp '(1 2)))
   (cond
      [(number? 2) (list `(hi ,var)
                         `(bye ,exp))]))
```

This returns

```
'((hi (make)) (bye (1 2)))
```

but *does not print* anything. Notice also that the comma ([unquote](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/qq.html)) now causes both local variables, var and exp, to be evaluated.

Chris Jester-Young's answer shows how to *print* the evaluated expressions, while *return*ing nothing.